# Python regex to match string containing characters with only alphabets numbers and '-' and '_' and not starting or ending with any special character

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing a regular expression to match the string with alphanumeric characters("-", "A-Z", "a-z", "0-9" and "_") and the string should be starting or ending with only alphabets("a-z" or "A-Z") or numbers ("0-9")

examples of valid strings: ["abcd-ef_df", "123_abc-def", "abcdef", "12345"]

example of invalid strings: ["_abc","abc-","abc$def"]

I tried below expression but it gives True for all types of strings:

```
if re.match('(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?', my_str):
    print True
```

Comment: It's always true because you've made the entire group optional with the `?` at the end. Was that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pattern `^[^\W_](?:[\w-]*[^\W_])?$`:

```
my_str = "123_abc-def"
if re.match(r'^[^\W_](?:[\w-]*[^\W_])?$', my_str):
    print("MATCH")
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
^                 from the start of the string
    [^\W_]        match an initial letter or number only
    (?:           (don't capture)
         [\w-]*   match zero or or more middle letters, numbers, _ or -
         [^\W_]   match a closing letter or number only
    )?            middle and final characters are optional
$                 end of the string
```